# Creating directory hierarchy in Android (for gallery)

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have some code like this:

```
photo = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "images/mydir/" + File.separator + timeStamp + ".jpg");
photo.getParentFile().mkdirs();
photo.createNewFile();
```

But in the gallery, I'm only seeing "mydir" with the photos inside it. No "images" directory to be found.

How do I create a hierarchy so there's an image folder and mydir is inside that?

Thanks

Comment: use slash before images and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and unfortunately it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your code as you have one `/` after mydir and you are also adding File.separator so final output will be `images/mydir//`

```
photo = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "images/mydir/" + File.separator + timeStamp + ".jpg");
```

Just remove the `/` after mydir like below

```
photo = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/images/mydir" + File.separator + timeStamp + ".jpg");
```

This should work now.

Comment: Thanks, good pick up! But it still only creates a mydir directory in the gallery when I'd like there to be an images directory, with mydir inside that. Is it possible to have subdirectories in the gallery?

Comment: It should allow you to have directory under the gallery, I have updated my answer, try to put `/` before the `images/mydir` and execute it again.

Comment: I tried with the leading slash too. I just see the "mydir" directory. I have a feeling that when I run `photo.getParentFile().mkdirs();` it's just looking at the parent of the jpg file, which is mydir. And not recognising the "images" part. Do you know if there's a way to (cleanly) programatically create "images" and then create "mydir" inside it?

Comment: cleaning a system folder may cause a serious problem, I suggest you to use an alternate way as create a folder image ( instead of `images` ) and then you can create a directory hierarchy inside it.

Comment: Hi, sorry - I may have misunderstood. Is "images" a system folder inside the gallery?

Comment: @b85411 , yes it is system folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46488/discussion-between-b85411-and-user3243163)